# sas proc slq where > datetime30.6

Tags: sql, sas, db2

I want to filter a table based on dates starting from 2022. But I can't seem to get the code working.

this is what I have tried:

```
PROC SQL;
CONNECT to db2 ;
create table mytable 
as select * from connection to DB2 
(SELECT * 
    FROM mytable
    where Datepart(Mydates) > '01JAN2022'd
     ); 
DISCONNECT from db2;
quit;
```

Mydates has the Datetime30.6 format

Kind regards

Comment: The code being run in DB2 needs to be DB2 code, not SAS code.  DATEPART() and the style of date literal you have are SAS syntax.  I added the DB2 tag to your question so perhaps someone that knows what methods for comparing datetime values work in that database.

Comment: @Tom thanks, now I at least know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tom who mentioned it had to be in DB2 code which I didn't know.
solution:

where Mydates > '2022-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Hi! I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem. Dont forget to accept your answer so we can know that this question is resolved. Thanks!